# Unable to access apex or sql-developer through Oracle Cloud web console 404

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, apex, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm having issues with the Oracle Cloud ADW (always free tier). The status of the server is available, but when I navigate to tools and click APEX or sql-developer I am met with the message:

404 Not Found --- *The request could not be mapped to any database. Check the request URL is correct, and that URL to database mappings have been correctly configured.*

When I navigate to the resource monitor, it seems that the server is running but all REST API calls fail. In using the web console to perform all these actions, any insight or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Email me your tenancy ID and region jeff.d.smith@oracle.com .. assuming you've tried restarting your instance

Comment: Problem identified, fix underway

Comment: As of the maintanence the 9th of August the problem has been resolved ^^